# Node.js Express : How to redirect page after processing post request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm, dao

How to redirect to different page from post request ?

```
module.exports = function(app) {
        app.post('/createStation', function(request, response){
            response.redirect('/'); //This doesn't work, why and how to make this work   
           /*var stationDao = require('./server/stationDao.js');
            stationDao.stationDao.createStation(request.body, function(status){
            if(status.status == 'successful'){
                response.redirect('/'); //This is what actually I wanted to do  
            }*/
        });
    });  
};
```

Tried using next() as well,

```
app.post('/createStation', [function(request, response, next){
        var stationDao = require('./server/stationDao.js');
        stationDao.stationDao.createStation(request.body, function(status){
            if(status.status == 'successful'){
                next();
            }
        });
    }, function abc(request, response){
        console.log('I can see this');
        response.redirect('/'); //This doesn't work still
    }]);
```

[image]

It actually triggers the GET request but the page won't redirect.

Since I am new in node.js, any kind of suggestion for the above code would be appreciated.

Comment: did you check if `status.status == 'successful'` works?

Comment: Have you tried writing the routine with the normal routing syntax, rather  than using `self.routeTable`?

Comment: No. Why would you think self.routeTable will be a problem ? Thanks

Comment: you need to set the statusCode to 302 and pass in the url you want to redirect to on the location header of the response https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302

Comment: hmm, the statusCode defaults to 302 in Express 4.x.x: [#res.redirect](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.redirect).  Running an older version maybe?

Comment: `response.redirect(302, '/'); This doesn't work for me.

Comment: Well, the reason i brought up `self.routeTable` is that I can't find any official documentation on its use.  Might be worth trying `app.post('/createStation',function(req,res){})`

Comment: can you share the part where u call `new routeConfig(app)`?

Comment: please find it on the updated question

Comment: Changed the routeConfig.js to simple one, still didn't work

Comment: This isn't an AJAX request is it? You're actually visiting the post page?

Comment: Request is made from an angular js form

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to leverage `next`, so something like

```
app.post('/', handlePostOnRoot);

app.post('/createStation', [
  function(req, res, next){
    next()       
  },
  handlePostOnRoot
]);
```

On the subject: http://expressjs.com/guide/routing.html#route-handlers

**EDIT** based on comment:

I've just wrote a really basic server to test what I wrote:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.post('/a', [function(req, res, next) {
  next();
}, function(req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!');
}]);

var server = app.listen(3000, function () { console.log('listening'); });
```

This works for me, I would encourage you to run that and then `curl -X POST http://localhost:3000/a`, in my case I correctly got "Hello World!".

If this also works for you try to isolate your problem a bit more by removing some bits and pieces.

Comment: Thanks, please find the updated question, I tried next() but didn't work

Comment: I wasn't expecting that :D well... might be express version then, which one are you using? I used the latest.

Comment: express => 3.4.4, nodejs => 4.2.2

Comment: I have express 4.13.3 and node 4.2.1

Comment: Then I'm sorry but can't help you there :D, I just tried again: created `/tmp/server.js` and run `npm install express` from `/tmp` and it worked fine, could you write the `curl` command you used to test it?

Answer (score 0):

Not an expert in Angular, but from what I can find, the form won't automatically follow the `/` redirect after doing the POST. Instead, people recommend using Angulars `$location.path('/');` to do a manual redirect after the form was submitted.