# Redirect page after post request [Express 4]

Tags: node.js, express

```
/**
 * @api {post} /logout Logout from system
 * @apiName Logout
 * @apiGroup Login
 */
router.post("/logout", function (req, res) {
  req.logout();
  req.session.destroy();
  return res.redirect("/");
});
```

I've read [Node.js Express : How to redirect page after processing post request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33624188/node-js-express-how-to-redirect-page-after-processing-post-request) but could not figure out the answer.

I recently changed logout to POST instead of GET. After doing so, redirect does'nt work

```
POST /logout 307 4.912 ms - 36
POST / 302 3.922 ms - 23
GET / 200 7.519 ms - -
```

I can manually do it on client side, but I want to know how to do it on server side as well. Is this possible?

**CLIENT**

HTML

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="logOut();">
```

JS

```
 function logOut() {
        $.post("/logout");
    }
```

Comment: Is your `/logout` route coming from an actual HTML form submission (no javascript involved) or a javascript generated ajax call?  I ask because there is no redirection from an Ajax call.

Comment: you cannot redirect from an ajax call.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are no redirects from a Javascript generated Ajax call which your `$.post()` is.  Ajax sends a request, gets a response.  An ajax call by itself does not change the page location at all.  That's a characteristic of Ajax calls.

Redirects work when the browser is loading a new page and the server tells it to change what page it is loading to a new source, not when the browser just sends an Ajax call.

You can, of course, use your client-side Javascript to decide to redirect from the client side after your `$.post()` finishes.  You could even have the response from the `$.post()` be the new location and your client-side Javascript could then just set `window.location` to that new URL.

```
function logOut() {
    $.post("/logout").then(function(data) {
        window.location = data.redirectUrl;
    });
}
```

And, on the server:

```
router.post("/logout", function (req, res) {
  req.logout();
  req.session.destroy();
  res.send({err: 0, redirectUrl: "/"});
});
```

Comment: I see! Implementation wise, what would be a good practice? For server to send a status code and lets the client decide? Or should I find a way to make the server refresh for the client?

Comment: @Zanko - I added an option for both client and server.

Comment: Thank you so much! The key lesson here is that redirection doesn't work with ajax call. So in other word, if ajax wasn't inform maybe a form submission will trigger a POST request that involves the browser loading a new page?

Comment: @Zanko - An HTML form post returns new content for the browser to display.  I don't know if you can use a 302 redirect there or not.  But, you can make the returned content be a simple page with a script that does the client side redirect you want.