# Trying to render a page from node js after making post request through angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, node.js

I am trying to render a page from nodejs after the post request from angular controller. However, the page doesn't load and it stays on the same page. There are no errors in the console. Moreover in the browser developer tools I can see page loaded under the Network--Preview Section.
Is this the correct or suggested way? I guess, the control comes back to controller rather than rendering the page from node.How Can we avoid this or is there a better way to do this?
Any help is appreciated.

Post request from controller:

```
$http({

                method : "POST",
                url: '/afterSignin',
                data: {
                        "inputUsername": $scope.inputUsername,
                        "inputPassword": $scope.inputPassword

                    }

                }).success(function(data)
                    {

                            if(data.statusCode==401)
                            {
                                $scope.msg = "Invalid Username or Password";
                            }

                            else
                            {
                                console.log(data.statusCode);
                                console.log("login successfull");


                            }
```

Server Side Code(afterSignIn.js)

```
mysql.fetchData(function(err,results){
        if(err){
            throw err;
        }
        else 
        {
            if(results.length > 0){
                console.log("valid Login");

                     res.render('successLogin', { data: results } , function(err, result) {

                    // render on success
                    if (!err) {
                        res.end(result);
                    }
                    // render or error
                    else {
                        res.end('An error occurred');
                        console.log(err);
                    }
                });
```

console output:

Connection closed..
DB Results:[object Object]
valid Login
[0mPOST /afterSignin [32m200 [0m103.425 ms -

[Chrome Console Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0x3Wd.png)

Comment: That render would be sent as response to the ajax call that `$http` makes. Unless you do something with that response nothing will change. Not really clear on what you are expecting to happen

Comment: This is kind of login app. Users login and after sucessfull login user should be redirected to homepage. Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Typically in an angular app that would be done through internal app router (single page application). If you want to completely reload the page then you would either not use `$http` to submit and use browser default form submit process or do a javascript redirect in success callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Look at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38449568/redirect-page-after-post-request-express-4)
There are a number of good solutions to this. Probably the easiest is to replace the URL of window:

```
$http({
    method : "POST",
    url: '/afterSignin',
    data: {
            "inputUsername": $scope.inputUsername,
            "inputPassword": $scope.inputPassword

        }
    }).success(function(data){
                if(data.statusCode==401) {
                    $scope.msg = "Invalid Username or Password";
                }else {
                    console.log(data.statusCode);

                    // Interesting part, redirect the user
                    $window.location = '/successLogin'
                }
    });
```

As you can see, after receiving a response that indicates that the login was successful, you can redirect the user on the client side. (You have to inject `$window` as a dependency of the service/controller.)

A better solution would be to use a client side router package, e.g. [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) (you should go this way).