# Node.js with Express does not redirect to external URL when using res.redirect()

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, redirect

I'm using `Node.js` with `Express` to redirect to an external `URL`. I have `MongoDB` holding my short URL's and their associated full urls. I grab the full URLs from the data. This is the code I have doing it:

```
router.get('/url/:shortUrl', async function (req, res) {
return await ShortUrlAccessor.redirectToFullUrl(req.params.shortUrl)
.then((response) => res.redirect(302, response.full),
    (error) =>  response.status(404).send(`Error finding ShortUrl:${error}`));
})
```

(`shortUrlAccessor` is referring to my model to perform the necessary `MongoDB` operation to grab the URL object)

I checked that `response.full` does in fact equal "https://www.google.com/". When I do go to `'localhost:3000/url/:shortUrl'` it doesn't redirect it goes to `"localhost:3000/url/8dfs0"` for example and stays on my web application.

When I test it out in `Postman` I get the `HTML` from the page I'm trying to redirect to but in the browser, it doesn't redirect to the external URL.

My frontend is using `React/Redux`. Not sure if that really plays a factor here.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Problem is probably on the front end. Can you post the code you're using on the client side to call the router?

Comment: My guess is this: [How to properly redirect in nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41078641/how-to-properly-redirect-in-nodejs-expressjs/41078774#41078774) and this: [Redirect after post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38449568/redirect-page-after-post-request-express-4/38449699#38449699).  If you're sending this request via an Ajax call, then Ajax calls don't change the current browser page by themselves, even when they receive a 3xx response.  The 302 response just goes to your Ajax code where you can decide what to do with that response in the client code.